# Material Design suggestions for edit button for each item

Tags: android, button

I wanted to add an edit button to each button in a list of items. Android action buttons should only be used once per view so those don't make sense. Is there any other way of doing it by following material guidelines? This button should be something that flies off and flies on depending on whether the overall edit button is pressed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use flat buttons because buttons pop from backgrounds, easily grab attention, and guide the user’s eye. [Here](http://wingedpost.org/2015/09/android-flat-button-tutorial-xml/) is a nice post about this

UPDATED:

To design a flat button effect you have to do the following

1. define your button and set background to a drawable which contains definitions for status pressed and status default
2. for status pressed write a drawable resource with solid color
3. for status default write a drawable with a item pointing to status pressed drawable as a background. And draw a lighter shape as another item with a android:bottom="2dp"

flat_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rect_pressed"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/rect_normal"/>
</selector>
```

rect_normal.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/rect_pressed" />

  <item android:bottom="@dimen/layer_padding">
      <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
          <solid android:color="@color/blue_normal" />
      </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

rect_pressed.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
  <solid android:color="@color/blue_pressed" />
</shape>
```

if you need to read the full tutorial [go here](http://wingedpost.org/2015/09/android-flat-button-tutorial-xml/).

Comment: Please avoid link only posts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @maciej-lach, added the code here

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [flat or raised button](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons) (depending on how important your edit function is).

Comment: but how would I make this button transition in, it seems like a pretty static button to me, I need something that will be there in edit mode and leave when out of edit mode

Comment: ok... next time you should try to specify your question better. Its not clear enough. So is there like one static button (lets call it button A) on every item of the list and another one (button B) should show up when you press A?

Comment: sorry for not explaining. So there is an overall edit button (button A) and there are individual edit button for every list entry (button B). Button B is not there at the start and when button A is pressed this shows/hides button B.

Comment: whats the style of your button A? and by "overall" you mean one button for whole list?

Comment: yes, it is an edit button in the taskbar replacing the overflow menu button

Comment: No the idea is to have an edit mode and edit individual items by their buttons

Comment: I would probably still go with flat or raised button. I would probably extend the height of the list items when entering edit mode, and show flat or raised button at the bottom.